# Firebase Snapshot equal to null when value exists

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically Im trying to query for reviews made on a certain post. So Im querying first in the database for the Posts (key) and all its corresponding data.. which in turn includes a list of ReviewID's These Ids you can see in my database picture. All of this I am getting successfully, the Issue is when I need to bring the review Data in from firebase it tells me the snapshot is null.... I have read a few things and I believe maybe this has something to do with being able to query inside a query.. can anyone help shed a light on this. Im not sure what to do because getting the corresponding reviews relies on the data in AddPost Node (Did this so data wouldn't become nested!)

// getting Post here

```
  func getPost(withKey key: String, completion: @escaping (_ addPost: AddPost?) - 
 > ()) {
 REF_ADDS.child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
            let addPost = AddPost(postKeyId: key, postData: snapshot)

            let reviewKeys = addPost.reviewIDs
            print("\(reviewKeys)")

           // Having Issues Here. am successfully getting the keys above^
            for key in reviewKeys {
                self.getReview(withKey: key, completion: { (reviews) in
                })               
            }           
            completion(addPost)           
        }
    })   
}
```

// getting corresponding reviews here

```
func getReview(withKey key: String, completion: @escaping (_ reviews: ReviewPost?) -> ()) {

    REF_REVIEWPOST.child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        print("getreviewsnapshot\(snapshot.value)")
        if let snapshot = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
            let review = ReviewPost(key: key, postData: snapshot)
            completion(review)
        }
    }
}
```

[AddPost firebase Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYjDG.png)

[ReviewPost firebase Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99bUz.png)

//Firebase JSON

```
{
  "AddPost" : {
    "-LIGEc5BRdMDPCOLaGIE" : {
      "endTime" : "02:41 PM 25/07/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F404483C2-1540-4E7B-86BC-5714CE2567E8?alt=media&token=421f4182-d364-41de-ba46-ebc8c6bcf78c",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "first test post",
      "reviews" : {
        "testttt" : true
      },
      "startTime" : "01:41 PM 25/07/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LIHJ3343uFw3vgkimk3" : {
      "endTime" : "07:41 PM 25/07/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F7BCC4D95-2F6D-405A-B9A2-4FBCB573514E?alt=media&token=94d76335-faf3-4437-b64d-0412cbdbd15f",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "anotherTestAdd",
      "startTime" : "06:40 PM 25/07/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LIQ_Aa8s1H067wFeCdR" : {
      "endTime" : "20:51PM 17/07/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F9310AD91-3744-4BC7-BB9F-29E423BC6675?alt=media&token=2e2efd5c-6d50-443e-9e8e-6901663a3c8b",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "Dumplings For FREE",
      "reviews" : {
        "-LKytNJZcNwrNom9mfhx)" : true
      },
      "startTime" : "19:51PM 27/07/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LIQjFPOYrNkRTCquRrP" : {
      "endTime" : "22:35PM 27/07/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F59472C4A-C8C5-4B9F-B72F-FAC00DE3624D?alt=media&token=bb81a21f-f367-4eac-b562-22b417e8f3ed",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "Chicken Noodles 9.99",
      "reviews" : {
        "-LKysthgvVyfjVf3nlNR)" : true,
        "-LL-6TMwUvyohrDXHmMU" : true
      },
      "startTime" : "20:35PM 27/07/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LIR6OEX48lAnInecbx3" : {
      "endTime" : "05:21 PM 27/07/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F782B0D7A-85E9-4ADA-A824-B5B094ABF4BA?alt=media&token=4cb5ffa5-b2a7-447f-b4aa-16ffccaa0e6d",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "testpost",
      "startTime" : "04:21 PM 27/07/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LIR8wRCXBirrYI4TrkA" : {
      "endTime" : "05:32 PM 27/07/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FA2543B6C-ECD2-4106-A8B0-FB9F73089EF1?alt=media&token=2d04f2c4-2048-4719-bd93-e58faf6837e8",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "hahahahaha ",
      "reviews" : {
        "-LIfeMknU_5uZQ0rKr20)" : true,
        "-LIfeQMzo8gMNqHAd7O2)" : true
      },
      "startTime" : "04:32 PM 27/07/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LJ3EjqT2xu1BCowKg-w" : {
      "endTime" : "11:20 AM 04/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FEBFB8D3F-31B6-4D13-856C-EE054B8AFC53?alt=media&token=74ec2aac-d3af-4ecf-99c2-87d92e8125bc",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "La desgracia ",
      "postTitle" : "two for one beers ",
      "startTime" : "10:20 AM 04/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-5s5j_JnfDJn2UyVM" : {
      "endTime" : "12:36 PM 29/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F7ABE207E-BBA4-467E-8956-C9AFF1D17FCF?alt=media&token=c40e0a05-ad28-49f5-ac5e-cbad4adf0cfb",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "la previa",
      "postTitle" : "la previa",
      "startTime" : "12:36 PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-7Y1mw7DvQPb-uC8Z" : {
      "endTime" : "19:43PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F548E96B8-A055-4615-8399-EB17D33D4184?alt=media&token=408992af-99e8-4e48-95fc-5bc8fe327097",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "a name",
      "startTime" : "18:43PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-9cU88j4mZkonAFw2" : {
      "endTime" : "20:52PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F9AAB98CF-AA20-43BE-AFB7-63811E15B685?alt=media&token=74ed6447-b6b7-42cd-9db6-31a7b41f1c60",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "Some stuff",
      "startTime" : "18:52PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-CPtZhtpHtT0PwvOH" : {
      "endTime" : "01:05 PM 18/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FC6075A46-2ADE-495A-87C5-1180B47A9933?alt=media&token=9bc6fd5a-f7ca-4710-9691-a8e50fce250e",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "la previa",
      "postTitle" : "hombre",
      "startTime" : "01:04 PM 18/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-G10SOxOlC-Mq2K0k" : {
      "endTime" : "01:20 PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F784E67BE-3D2C-44C6-A0F8-C1FBAFE5C5D5?alt=media&token=aea5b7fe-bd9d-4b90-8c6d-d568fe3ad3c2",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "la previa",
      "postTitle" : "ahha",
      "startTime" : "01:20 PM 18/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-Gd6NkAVCl5EjV_wy" : {
      "endTime" : "21:23PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FD305CE5C-6865-4C14-A7CF-2E5DD8291116?alt=media&token=6fc0ffc8-4f61-4198-818b-e41857fa0190",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "Beef Super Noodles",
      "reviews" : {
        "-LL-Gz7N4qx_t0vYnsnn" : true
      },
      "startTime" : "20:23PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-HWJ_pan1DC1RVC11" : {
      "endTime" : "23:26PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FAD49348A-AB8F-4362-9E02-ABAE45BB8A71?alt=media&token=06be5ba5-c555-4d26-a06b-dd752ec7b8b1",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "Fast Dumplings Forever",
      "startTime" : "18:26PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-JBuCmVANW_wRlc6Y" : {
      "endTime" : "20:34PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F24FA64CB-7E58-45A3-94EE-1E7FC0922232?alt=media&token=1d537867-8d91-4ea5-bac8-e2e402dbec99",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "Fish tart",
      "startTime" : "19:34PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-MKQhf2XGp3uEfWxw" : {
      "endTime" : "01:48 PM 18/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FE2EF7170-00C0-4B4D-B299-631647080009?alt=media&token=87b54b2c-0720-4d02-9a8f-14c73e8936cb",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "la previa",
      "postTitle" : "as?",
      "startTime" : "01:48 PM 18/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-Mi43AcCE1CjA_Z1z" : {
      "endTime" : "20:50PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FA32A8B49-99FB-4353-8DF5-A9F9AC1AF506?alt=media&token=afd11f86-a02c-4680-a26b-54c8d43305f9",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "Kawabanga",
      "startTime" : "19:50PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-NJ2EvSKhYjgQ5j5M" : {
      "endTime" : "20:52PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F0113B93A-36ED-4A37-B02D-2098C1FF3600?alt=media&token=d9c83883-9f41-495c-a7e7-4aaa33d6eaf6",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "some sad stuff",
      "startTime" : "20:52PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-P6dK9SaQ2wvhvjXl" : {
      "endTime" : "21:00PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FA57F2466-9E6F-45E4-85CD-2AFBAE0D1CF5?alt=media&token=93be27a0-b70b-436f-8e5e-16d5f3d051b4",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "fakdkfm",
      "startTime" : "20:00PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-PE13Mbc-aB-uzlTo" : {
      "endTime" : "02:01 PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FF628CBE2-B34C-48F2-AD9F-AF7F889716C7?alt=media&token=674d107b-706b-426e-9205-f6497c37f311",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "la previa",
      "postTitle" : "test",
      "startTime" : "02:00 PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-S3BSycT6jCGYrQKb" : {
      "endTime" : "02:13 PM 18/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2F46E21030-F88B-463A-8A76-64B92C02B42B?alt=media&token=e013e775-3fab-41dc-88b7-0577cf1c48ea",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "la previa",
      "postTitle" : "ah",
      "startTime" : "02:13 PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-SMMxpgT2w-aC0HK5" : {
      "endTime" : "20:15PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FB0D6A779-ECA0-4856-873F-CF8B72058AC0?alt=media&token=6d25e66a-4fd3-43ab-b7c8-df3a0d37de9d",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "ggggg",
      "startTime" : "20:14PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-Sur61fCG8Uz9_NRU" : {
      "endTime" : "20:17PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FC0D9C742-3432-47F4-B54B-E87C923D32EB?alt=media&token=f187e783-d251-48f4-ac3a-c5ae808ff092",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "Noname",
      "startTime" : "20:17PM 28/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    },
    "-LL-UiIvutVi0BqCJM-S" : {
      "endTime" : "02:25 PM 28/08/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/posts%2FAA9D0DF5-455D-4BC1-9496-DFB3CED331EE?alt=media&token=de25c0ed-50d6-448d-8e30-54891837d08a",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "la previa",
      "postTitle" : "hahahahaha ",
      "startTime" : "02:25 PM 18/08/2018",
      "views" : 0
    }
  },
  "Geolocs" : {
    "6oQkKd6KWFfBHZKpe6qAU3nGdzE2" : {
      "g" : "ezjpm00vzk",
      "l" : [ 40.6504274, -3.997676599999999 ]
    },
    "IMDdQqucvubaoCQK37ih1WW0SCE2" : {
      "g" : "ezjphu9ryz",
      "l" : [ 40.6315578, -4.0079973 ]
    },
    "LUtRmkAefPNsRjPni5Dn0KAvKBx1" : {
      "g" : "w7jzu4b4s3",
      "l" : [ 18.252847, 109.511909 ]
    },
    "iY92WUP59NfBwpPooRvcCMtOt5A2" : {
      "g" : "w7jzspq2y7",
      "l" : [ 18.23333, 109.520572 ]
    },
    "m0dOavnabOOwvU2D96gOAZMHN8H2" : {
      "g" : "ezjpkbw83c",
      "l" : [ 40.6522097, -4.0010055 ]
    },
    "shAsayRaoWSreayG5wKF2aTPMkh1" : {
      "g" : "ezjpm003w9",
      "l" : [ 40.64967947910633, -3.9984001591801643 ]
    },
    "vKdlBRpiiTS3IArFhTo8KHCRN0H2" : {
      "g" : "ezjpkbpr3n",
      "l" : [ 40.65069163457745, -4.0000031143426895 ]
    },
    "x748UBl3VRQk5zdruYKjw5RayTt1" : {
      "g" : "9q8yyrpvjx",
      "l" : [ 37.78837619999999, -122.4097711 ]
    }
  },
  "ReviewPost" : {
    "-LINUam-sdDpLpPYPlnL" : {
      "addPostID" : "-LIGEc5BRdMDPCOLaGIE",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "This is test review ",
      "time" : "2018-07-26 21:28:41 +0000",
      "userID" : "IMDdQqucvubaoCQK37ih1WW0SCE2"
    },
    "-LIfd7XGrHXpftKvZN3I" : {
      "addPostID" : "-LIR8wRCXBirrYI4TrkA",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "Test comment /review :) ",
      "time" : "2018-07-30 14:43:06 +0000",
      "userID" : "shAsayRaoWSreayG5wKF2aTPMkh1"
    },
    "-LIfdIGpdo2ZTk03sh7F" : {
      "addPostID" : "-LIGEc5BRdMDPCOLaGIE",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "Another test ",
      "time" : "2018-07-30 14:43:50 +0000",
      "userID" : "shAsayRaoWSreayG5wKF2aTPMkh1"
    },
    "-LIfdTGE5adLuyIwhNtf" : {
      "addPostID" : "-LIGEc5BRdMDPCOLaGIE",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "Test2",
      "time" : "2018-07-30 14:44:35 +0000",
      "userID" : "shAsayRaoWSreayG5wKF2aTPMkh1"
    },
    "-LIfeMknU_5uZQ0rKr20" : {
      "addPostID" : "-LIR8wRCXBirrYI4TrkA",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "Test 3",
      "time" : "2018-07-30 14:48:30 +0000",
      "userID" : "shAsayRaoWSreayG5wKF2aTPMkh1"
    },
    "-LIfeQMzo8gMNqHAd7O2" : {
      "addPostID" : "-LIR8wRCXBirrYI4TrkA",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "Otra test en la ",
      "time" : "2018-07-30 14:48:45 +0000",
      "userID" : "shAsayRaoWSreayG5wKF2aTPMkh1"
    },
    "-LKysthgvVyfjVf3nlNR" : {
      "addPostID" : "-LIQjFPOYrNkRTCquRrP",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "Shitty place",
      "time" : "2018-08-28 04:56:10 +0000",
      "userID" : "LUtRmkAefPNsRjPni5Dn0KAvKBx1"
    },
    "-LKytNJZcNwrNom9mfhx" : {
      "addPostID" : "-LIQ_Aa8s1H067wFeCdR",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "Dumplings were rubbish.",
      "time" : "2018-08-28 04:58:18 +0000",
      "userID" : "LUtRmkAefPNsRjPni5Dn0KAvKBx1"
    },
    "-LL-6TMwUvyohrDXHmMU" : {
      "addPostID" : "-LIQjFPOYrNkRTCquRrP",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "Rubishhhhhhh",
      "time" : "2018-08-28 10:39:27 +0000",
      "userID" : "LUtRmkAefPNsRjPni5Dn0KAvKBx1"
    },
    "-LL-Gz7N4qx_t0vYnsnn" : {
      "addPostID" : "-LL-Gd6NkAVCl5EjV_wy",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "That was awesome!!!!!!",
      "time" : "2018-08-28 11:25:23 +0000",
      "userID" : "iY92WUP59NfBwpPooRvcCMtOt5A2"
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "208icyabSsT5jYhbxhPgIv4JmjF2" : {
      "City" : "Abhudabi ",
      "Country" : "Mars",
      "Name" : {
        "Nickname" : "Vvvvvvvv"
      },
      "isBusiness" : false
    },
    "6oQkKd6KWFfBHZKpe6qAU3nGdzE2" : {
      "businessName" : "Tarssss",
      "city" : "Collado Villalba ",
      "country" : "Spain",
      "isBusiness" : true,
      "lat" : 40.6504274,
      "lon" : -3.997676599999999,
      "ownersName" : "Tar",
      "postcode" : "28400",
      "state" : "Madrid",
      "street" : "Calle la chopera 3"
    },
    "7qk6HTr6jxV23GeF1C6faOrXSkm2" : {
      "businessName" : "Ya",
      "city" : "Collado Villalba ",
      "country" : "Spain",
      "isBusiness" : true,
      "ownersName" : "Ya",
      "postcode" : "28400",
      "state" : "Madrid",
      "street" : "Calle la chopera 2 "
    },
    "9XUMX4iTeogAj4KS3Icu77jDCbC2" : {
      "businessName" : "T",
      "city" : "Collado Villalba ",
      "country" : "Spain",
      "isBusiness" : true,
      "ownersName" : "T",
      "postcode" : "28400",
      "state" : "Madrid",
      "street" : "Calle la chopera 2 "
    },
    "AmUqAzjf3gXvLGPzV8O7KE3Q5tq2" : {
      "City" : "Fndksks",
      "Country" : "Dnmddkk",
      "Name" : {
        "Nickname" : "Alfjfkk"
      },
      "isBusiness" : false
    },
    "BihBfwdWKhazFwuLtWFTo31GAu42" : {
      "City" : "VC",
      "Country" : "Vvvvv",
      "Name" : {
        "Nickname" : "VC"
      },
      "isBusiness" : false
    },
    "FysXUqOJ1aXyQGYyhg03AtO09my2" : {
      "city" : "Amfkdkdkdkd",
      "country" : "Xmxkkxkdkdkd",
      "isBusiness" : false,
      "name" : "Aldo"
    },
    "IMDdQqucvubaoCQK37ih1WW0SCE2" : {
      "addPosts" : {
        "-LIHJ3343uFw3vgkimk3" : true,
        "-LL-5s5j_JnfDJn2UyVM" : true,
        "-LL-CPtZhtpHtT0PwvOH" : true,
        "-LL-G10SOxOlC-Mq2K0k" : true,
        "-LL-MKQhf2XGp3uEfWxw" : true,
        "-LL-PE13Mbc-aB-uzlTo" : true,
        "-LL-S3BSycT6jCGYrQKb" : true,
        "-LL-UiIvutVi0BqCJM-S" : true
      },
      "businessName" : "la previa",
      "email" : "laprevia@hotmail.com",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/ProfilePics%2FD7617CAA-B31A-468C-8D8A-FCAA6265CC3A?alt=media&token=06a313bf-2db1-414c-a0d0-483b23872063",
      "isBusiness" : true,
      "lat" : 40.6315578,
      "lon" : -4.0079973,
      "profileName" : "tar",
      "reviews" : {
        "-LINUam-sdDpLpPYPlnL" : true
      }
    },
    "LUtRmkAefPNsRjPni5Dn0KAvKBx1" : {
      "addPosts" : {
        "-LIQ_Aa8s1H067wFeCdR" : true,
        "-LIQjFPOYrNkRTCquRrP" : true,
        "-LL-7Y1mw7DvQPb-uC8Z" : true,
        "-LL-9cU88j4mZkonAFw2" : true
      },
      "businessName" : "DumplingMania",
      "city" : "Sanya",
      "country" : "China",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodies-a4b80.appspot.com/o/ProfilePics%2F38E4C97A-B636-452A-92FD-3A179BFB15A9?alt=media&token=687b0096-758d-4055-864a-19db67722313",
      "isBusiness" : true,
      "lat" : 18.252847,
      "lon" : 109.511909,
      "ownersName" : "Mr. Dumpling",
      "postcode" : "572000",
      "reviews" : {
        "-LKysthgvVyfjVf3nlNR" : true,
        "-LKytNJZcNwrNom9mfhx" : true,
        "-LL-6TMwUvyohrDXHmMU" : true
      },
      "state" : "Hainan",
      "street" : "Hedong"
    },
    "ZhnyfjmjG4P3kQKxWI74y55OeVj2" : {
      "City" : "Mick city ",
      "Country" : "Mars",
      "Name" : {
        "Nickname" : "Nick nickname"
      },
      "isBusiness" : false
    },
    "iY92WUP59NfBwpPooRvcCMtOt5A2" : {
      "addPosts" : {
        "-LL-Gd6NkAVCl5EjV_wy" : true,
        "-LL-HWJ_pan1DC1RVC11" : true,
        "-LL-JBuCmVANW_wRlc6Y" : true,
        "-LL-Mi43AcCE1CjA_Z1z" : true,
        "-LL-NJ2EvSKhYjgQ5j5M" : true,
        "-LL-P6dK9SaQ2wvhvjXl" : true,
        "-LL-SMMxpgT2w-aC0HK5" : true,
        "-LL-Sur61fCG8Uz9_NRU" : true
      },
      "businessName" : "NoodleDoodle",
      "city" : "Sanya",
      "country" : "China",
      "isBusiness" : true,
      "lat" : 18.23333,
      "lon" : 109.520572,
      "ownersName" : "NoodleDoodle",
      "postcode" : "572000",
      "reviews" : {
        "-LL-Gz7N4qx_t0vYnsnn" : true
      },
      "state" : "Hainan",
      "street" : "Fenghuang"
    },
    "m0dOavnabOOwvU2D96gOAZMHN8H2" : {
      "addPosts" : {
        "-LIGEc5BRdMDPCOLaGIE" : true
      },
      "businessName" : "testBusiness1",
      "email" : "test1@hotmail.com",
      "imageUrl" : "defaultImgHere?",
      "isBusiness" : true,
      "lat" : 40.6522097,
      "lon" : -4.0010055,
      "profileName" : "test1"
    },
    "shAsayRaoWSreayG5wKF2aTPMkh1" : {
      "businessName" : "Gemany",
      "city" : "Collado Villalba",
      "country" : "Spain",
      "isBusiness" : true,
      "lat" : 40.64967947910633,
      "lon" : -3.9984001591801643,
      "ownersName" : "Gema ",
      "postcode" : "28400",
      "reviews" : {
        "-LIfd7XGrHXpftKvZN3I" : true,
        "-LIfdIGpdo2ZTk03sh7F" : true,
        "-LIfdTGE5adLuyIwhNtf" : true,
        "-LIfeMknU_5uZQ0rKr20" : true,
        "-LIfeQMzo8gMNqHAd7O2" : true
      },
      "state" : "Madrid",
      "street" : "Calle la chopera "
    },
    "uU6IAhEUKzQXTK4P4Gn4zn0gIjB3" : {
      "City" : "Fmcmdk",
      "Country" : "Ndsmmskx",
      "Name" : {
        "Nickname" : "Flank"
      },
      "isBusiness" : false
    },
    "vKdlBRpiiTS3IArFhTo8KHCRN0H2" : {
      "addPosts" : {
        "-LIR8wRCXBirrYI4TrkA" : true
      },
      "businessName" : "Hola ",
      "city" : "Collado Villalba ",
      "country" : "Spain ",
      "isBusiness" : true,
      "lat" : 40.6500548,
      "lon" : -3.9976061,
      "ownersName" : "Hola ",
      "postcode" : "28400",
      "state" : "Madrid ",
      "street" : "Calle chopera 2"
    },
    "x748UBl3VRQk5zdruYKjw5RayTt1" : {
      "Business Name" : "Dumplings Inc.",
      "City" : "Dumpling City",
      "Country" : "Dumpling Country",
      "Owners Name" : {
        "Nickname" : "Dumpling Master"
      },
      "Postcode" : "0112233",
      "State" : "Dumpling State",
      "Street" : "Big Street",
      "lat" : 37.78837619999999,
      "lon" : -122.4097711
    },
    "yMIiHPtJQdYspZhK61ZQa0MqNan1" : {
      "City" : "V",
      "Country" : "V",
      "Name" : {
        "Nickname" : "Val"
      },
      "isBusiness" : false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include your datastructure as text instead of an image.

Comment: Not sure about that its a very big database.. it also reads the same as the screenshot.

Comment: @Tasha You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the database is rather large but I have included it in edit, thanks again for the help.

Comment: A couple of things; you are not querying inside a query. You are observing a node to obtain child node key. Then iterating those child nodes to get the posts. There's actually nothing wrong with that technique, although putting an observe in a tight loop like that may not be the best idea. Also, if you did use queries, there's no problem nesting them. Lastly, your structure is not too deep and there's nothing wrong with it, other than it's too much to be in the question! A snippet would suffice. But....

Comment: ... I would take a different approach. I would add a child node to each review called *post_id: some_post_id*. To then get all of the reviews, just query on the reviews node for all reviews what that post id. Super simple, easy to maintain and a lot less code.

Comment: I see.. I do actually have the postiD child node your talking about.. the value is the post it is commenting on.. I will give that a try:D if you could give me an example I would love to test it. meanwhile I will also try myself. @Jay

Comment: Oh - and to address the issue. First it's probably not a good idea to keep reusing a variable with the same name. The code has a *key* passed in and that is passed to the AddPost object and then re-used in your loop. It becomes hard to read. We also don't know what addPost is *let addPost = AddPost(postKeyId: key, postData: snapshot)* - did you trying print(addPost) and inspecting the strings? We also don't know how *REF_REVIEWPOST* is defined. Also, you could have firebase rules in place preventing a read.

Comment: I checked for all errors that could be caused because of Naming, those are just constants(REF_REVIEWPOST) but if you'd like I can put those here.. as for the naming totally agree I see that now, my bad @Jay

Comment: A few print statements just to verify they strings are what you think would be a good idea. The addPost var is suspect to me. Before spending a lot of time on that however, check my answer.

Comment: Ok Im going to give this all a try when my Xcode isnt pooping itself.. its having some issues right now. Once I try the answer if it works Ill be sure to mark it as accepted @Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other issues with the code but I would suggest a different approach. Instead of a tight loop to read in the reviews about each post, just include the post_id in each review and then a simple query to read them in.

```
Posts
  "post_id_0" : { //childByAutoId()
      "endTime" : "05:32 PM 27/07/2018",
      "imageUrl" : "",
      "live" : true,
      "locationName" : "",
      "postTitle" : "hahahahaha ",
      "reviews" : {
        "review_id_0" : true,
        "review_id_1" : true
      },
      "startTime" : "04:32 PM 27/07/2018",
      "views" : 0

ReviewPost
    "review_id_0" : { //childByAutoId()
      "post_id": "post_id_0", //a reference to the post
      "addPostID" : "-LIQ_Aa8s1H067wFeCdR",
      "rating" : 5,
      "reviewComment" : "Dumplings were rubbish.",
      "time" : "2018-08-28 04:58:18 +0000",
      "userID" : "LUtRmkAefPNsRjPni5Dn0KAvKBx1"
    },
```

then to get all of the reviews for post_id_0

```
let reviewPostRef = self.ref.child("ReviewPost")
let query = reviewPostRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "post_id").queryEqual(toValue: "post_id_0")
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
        let comment = dict["reviewComment"] as! String
        print(comment)
    }
})
```

and the output is

```
Dumplings were rubbish.
```

Comment: This worked thankyou very much @Jay Im still unsure as to why my other way did not work but what you suggested worked like a charm and I didn't have to change any datamodels or structures :D well done